# snakemake (or parallel) for multiple machines over ssh

Tags: hpc, snakemake, gnu-parallel

Say you have a snakemake file. This file produces something like 50000 jobs, however, these are small jobs that take a few seconds to run.

From the head node, you have access to multiple servers named:

```
machine01
machine02
machine03
machine04
machine05
machine06
```

To make matters more interesting, each machine has an uneven number of cores. What is the best way to send the different jobs to different machines for parallel execution? I tried the batch option in snakemake but it does not seem to be doing but I thought it did.

Comment: For jobs on the scale of seconds you might want to switch to dask.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev ok maybe not 1-2 seconds but say 30-100s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU Parallel it could look like this:

```
cat arguments | parallel --slf list-of-servers my_script
```

If GNU Parallel is installed the servers, it will detect the number of cores on each server.

Comment: I tried this but it seems that it running:
     ssh machine01-- exec perl -e @GNU_Parallel\\\=split/_/,\
and it goes on.
I tried instead:
     cat commands | parallel --slf list-of-servers 
Is this wrong?

Comment: Both are  normal. The exec sets up the environment before running you command.